# Kendo grid filtering on integer column when typing

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a grid with multiple columns.
say `Id(integer)`,`Name(string)` etc.
Change event is working fine for name column.But for ID column it is not working.

I want this functionality to be in server side(Razor).

I am new to Kendo UI and any help on how to do this would be much appreciated.

I am attaching my code below:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("ViewDataGrid")

    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Title(" ID").Width(150);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Title(" Name").Width(150);

        })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: auto; width: 2200px" })
    .Filterable(i => i.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu | GridFilterMode.Row))
    .Sortable(s => s.AllowUnsort(false).SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
    .Selectable(selecting => selecting.Enabled(true))                               
    .Pageable(r => r.PreviousNext(true).PageSizes(new int[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100 }))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Events(e => e.Change("call"))
        ))
function call(e) {

    if (e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters != null) {
        if (e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[0].value == "") {                     
            $('#ViewDataGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.filter({});
        }
        else {
            var filterlength = e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters.length;
            $filter = new Array();
            if (e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[0].field == "Id")
            $filter.push({ field: e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[0].field, operator: "eq", value: e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[0].value });
            else
            $filter.push({ field: e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[0].field, operator: "contains", value: e.sender.filter.arguments[0].filters[0].value });
            $("#ViewDataGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter($filter);

        }
    }
}
```

#### Model.CS

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
```

#### Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<GridData> dataList = new List<GridData>(); 
    GridData data1 = new GridData();
    data1.Id = 9191919;
    data1.Name = "XYZ";           
    dataList.Add(data1);
    return View(dataList);           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using "row" selection type:

```
.Selectable(selecting => selecting.Enabled(true).Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
```